# Use CustomValidator to allow textbox to allow different input depending on previous option, VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am fairly new to VB.NET and I am trying to create a custom validator that will control the input in a textbox depending on a previous option. The option is what type of employement the user has which is selected via radiobuttons. 
The textbox should then allow decimal numbers for option 1 and not allow it for option 2

This is the current ASP code i have:

```
<asp:TableCell Width="200" ID="lblSalary" runat="server">Salary: </asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell Width="200" ID="lblSalaryPerHour"> Salary per Hour : </asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell Width="200"><asp:TextBox ID="tbSalary" runat="server" TabIndex="300"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="valSalary" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Lön" 
     OnServerValidate="expressionValidator" ControlToValidate="tbSalary" Text="*"></asp:CustomValidator>
    </asp:TableCell>
```

and the VB code so far is:

```
Protected Sub expressionValidator(ByVal _source As System.Object, ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
        If (_accType.ToLower = "employeehourly") Then

        Else

        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a really broad question, what actually are you asking? Can you not do an If statement? `If radiobutton1.Checked = True Then TextBox1.Text = "myText"` or something?

Comment: If you want to check for decimals, either use a regular expression or maybe use the Parse / TryParse methods (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.single.aspx)

Comment: True, it is a bit broad but you were correct in your idea @David , I found a solution that did the trick with similar syntax. Thanks for the answer.
This is the solution that did the trick:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Custom-Validator-Server-Side-validation-using-OnServerValidate-event.aspx